# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser как заставить перейти к полной новости скрипт?

Tags: php, парсер, dom

Помогите пожалуйста, очень прошу .. 
Проблема заключается в том что получаю массив ссылок, если перейти по которым будет полная новость, а вот как заставить парсер перейти не понимаю, умный человек объясни пожалуйста...

```
 function parser_simple_html($url, $i){
    if($i < 1) {
 $html = str_get_html(get_result($url));
    $blog = $html->find("#dle-content", 0);
    foreach ($blog->find(".post") as $root) {
        $film = $root->find(".post-title", 0)->find('a', 0)->href;  
        // $film - получили массив ссылок
        print $film; // как пробежаться по эти ссылкам ?? 
    }
// находим следующую страницу   
$page1 =  $blog->find('.navigation', 0)->find('a', 10)->next_sibling ()->href;
$page2 =  $blog->find('.navigation', 0)->find('a', 9)->next_sibling ()->href;
 if ($page1 == true){
    $page =  $blog->find('.navigation', 0)->find('a', 10)->next_sibling ()->href; 
  } else {
       $page =  $blog->find('.navigation', 0)->find('a', 9)->next_sibling ()->href;    
  } 
// конец поиска следующей страницы

// переходим на следующую страницу
if ((isset($page)) && !empty ($page)){
     $i++;
     parser_simple_html('' . $page . '', $i);
}       
 }
}
$i = 0;
parser_simple_html('http://дле-сайт.ру/page/1/', $i);
```

Новый вид программы :

```
  // ----------------- Вспомогательные функции.
    // Выносим в функцию, так как может поменяться способ получения файла.
    function getHtmlDocument($url) {
        return  file_get_html($url);
    }
    function getLinksFromDocument($htmlDoc) {
        // код который вернет все  ссылки в массиве.
        // Поменяйте ваш код что бы он только ссылки возвращал.
        $ssil = '';
        $html = getHtmlDocument('http://dle-site.ru/page/1/');
       $blog = $html->find("#dle-content", 0);
        foreach ($blog->find(".post") as $root) {
         $ssil .= $root->find(".post-title", 0)->find('a', 0)->href . ' ';


    }  
$s  = $ssil;
$ssilka = explode(" ", $s);

        return [$ssilka];
    }
    function getArticleInfo($htmlDoc) {
      $tittle = $articlesInfo->find("#dle-content", 0)->find(".post", 0)->find(".post-title", 0)->find('a', 0)->plaintext;
        return [
            "title" => $tittle, // тут допишите сами
            "content" => $tittle // тут допешите тоже сами
        ];
    }
    // ----------------- Вспомогательные функции.

    // ----------------- Сама программа.
    // Получаем документ в котором есть список ссылок
    $htmlDocument = getHtmlDocument('http://dle-site.ru/page/1/');

    // Парсим документ что бы получить список ссылок только
    $linkList = getLinksFromDocument($htmlDocument);
    // Пустой массив с информацией о статьях
    $articlesInfo = [];
    // Для каждой ссылки получаем документ.

   foreach ($linkList as $link) {
       $articleDocument = getHtmlDocument($link);
       // Парсим эти полученные документы.
       $articlesInfo[$link] = getArticleInfo($link);
    }
    // Здесь переменная $articlesInfo содержит всю информацию о всех статьях.
    // ----------------- Сама программа.
```

Comment: Что в вашем понимании "пробежаться"? Что вы хотите сделать с полученными ссылками?

Comment: Начните здесь http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php.

Comment: @DmitryZasypkin хочу что бы парсер переходил на каждую ссылку из массива и брал описание статьи или же хотя бы название статьи из класса post-title

Comment: @E_p спасибо , читал, и не только эту статью ... но увы нет наставника который подскажет что я делаю не правильно и почему ... читал книгу по php, на тех примерах что давали в книге вроде всё понятно и ясно , а как что то делаю не по примерам, так все катится верх дном ... ) почему и прошу помощи что б объяснили

Comment: @КостяКоростелев сделайте функцию по обработке этих ссылок и натравите её на полученный массив

Comment: @DmitryZasypkin Спасибо , завтра попробую )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если мало опыта программирования, то надо не с копирования кода начинать, а с описания того что происходит.

Алгоритм у вашей программы очень прост:

1. Получаем документ в котором есть список ссылок
2. Парсим документ что бы получить список ссылок только
3. Для каждой ссылки получаем документ.
4. Парсим эти полученные документы.

Можете использовать это как коментарии в коде. Мета программа которая ничего не делает.
Потом смотрите и думаете. 1-й и 3-й пункт у вас совпадают. Так что можно писать общую функцию.

Теперь можно начинать писать код.

```
<?php

    // ----------------- Вспомогательные функции.
    // Выносим в функцию, так как может поменяться способ получения файла.
    function getHtmlDocument($url) {
        return  file_get_html($url);
    }

    function getLinksFromDocument($htmlDoc) {
        // код который вернет все  ссылки в массиве.
        // Поменяйте ваш код что бы он только ссылки возвращал.
        return []
    }

    function getArticleInfo($htmlDoc) {
        return [
            "title" => "", // тут допишите сами
            "content" => ""// тут допешите тоже сами
        ];
    }
    // ----------------- Вспомогательные функции.


    // ----------------- Сама программа.
    // Получаем документ в котором есть список ссылок
    $htmlDocument = getHtmlDocument('http://дле-сайт.ру/page/1/');

    // Парсим документ что бы получить список ссылок только
    $linkList = getLinksFromDocument($htmlDocument);

    // Пустой массив с информацией о статьях
    $articlesInfo = [];
    // Для каждой ссылки получаем документ.
    foreach ($linkList as $link) {
        $articleDocument = getHtmlDocument($link);
        // Парсим эти полученные документы.
        $articlesInfo[$link] = getArticleInfo($link);
    }

    // Здесь переменная $articlesInfo содержит всю информацию о всех статьях.
    // ----------------- Сама программа.
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное за помощь)) расписали всё очень хорошо )

Comment: Добрый день , вот прошел час как я ломал голову, и так не понял функцию `function getArticleInfo($htmlDoc)` как он работает ?) что дописывать  ) как она будет работать в `foreach`?  после того как я собрал массив ссылок , пошли ошибки

Comment: @КостяКоростелев Покажите новый код.

Comment: извините за неграмотность, но я наверное не совсем понял как работать с документами , как вывести из документа массив который получается в результате `foreach`